# custom layout to listview add OnClickListener in inside of custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i have a listview to show my custom layout .
in custom layout i have a RatingBar or any think, want to set a action them!
how to add OnClickListener to my RatingBar in custom layout.
i set listview adapter in my main activity .

```
adapter = new ListviewBooksList(this, bookList);
lstBook.setAdapter(adapter);
```

work and see information but i don't understant how to add OnClickListener To my RatingBar in custom layout inside!

```
public class ListviewBooksList extends BaseAdapter {
static final String KEY_NAME = "bookName";
static final String KEY_FAV = "fav";
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;    
public ListviewBooksList(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}
public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {

    HashMap<String, String> nameList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    nameList = data.get(position);
    return nameList;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_books, null);
    TextView bookName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.listveiw_books_name);
    RatingBar fav = (RatingBar)vi.findViewById(R.id.star_fav_books);
    nameList = data.get(position);
    bookName.setText(nameList.get(KEY_NAME));
    fav.setRating(Float.valueOf(nameList.get(KEY_FAV)));
    return vi;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just to add the listener to the RatingBar in the getView() method, when you generate the view for the list item.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_books, null);
    TextView bookName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.listveiw_books_name);
    RatingBar fav = (RatingBar)vi.findViewById(R.id.star_fav_books);
    nameList = data.get(position);
    bookName.setText(nameList.get(KEY_NAME));
    fav.setRating(Float.valueOf(nameList.get(KEY_FAV)));

    fav.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {   
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            // action to perform when event is triggered            
        }     
    });

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: work, thanks .but my listview onclick now don't work . and just ratingbar clicking work .